# How to create dynamic/relative file path location in iMacros?

Tags: javascript, firefox, imacros

I want to use dynamic path for my iMacros

from

```
C:\\Users\\abcd\\Desktop\\folder\\file_name.csv
```

to something like

```
..\\file_name.csv
```

I'm using

```
Pale Moon Version 28.7.2
iMacros Free 8.9.7
windows 10
```

Answer (score 1):

i found one solution

instead of

```
C:\\Users\\abcd\\Documents\\iMacros\\Datasources\\file_name.csv
```

i can use this one

```
{{!FOLDER_DATASOURCE}}\\file_name.csv
```

but the folder need to be in imacros document not in desktop.